# Wrong username picked by the %USERNAME% variable

Tags: windows, cmd

Some login problem came with my previous user account. Therefore, the Admin created a new User account for me in the same PC.

**PROBLEM:** Now I have to write a common script (which will be used in other PCs too). In this script I have to specify the path of **Desktop**. I am using the following command (only example here) line which works everywhere except my PC

```
cd "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop"
pause
```

***It is not working in my PC because it is assigning the old username to the `%USERNAME%` variable and therefore trying to enter the Desktop of previous username which does not exist anymore (I removed the old user folder).***

How can I get the correct user name (new user name) assigned to the `%USERNAME%` variable?

Comment: Have you tried with `%userprofile%\Desktop`?

Comment: Yes, I tried `cd "C:\Users\%userprofile%\Desktop"` but it gives error that `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: That's the wrong syntax too, try `CD "%UserProfile%\Desktop"`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

Comment: Note: The Desktop folder can be moved to other places (outside the profile folder) so no matter what you do, you will never get this to work on 100% of all machines...

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the folder configured as *Desktop* for the current user from the registry

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
        reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v desktop
        ^| find "REG_"
    ') do call set "desktopFolder=%%b"

    echo %desktopFolder%
```

Note that as by default the registry key requested is of `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type, it can contain environment variables references that need to be expanded. That is the reason for the `call set` and not a direct `set`, we need to force a second parse of the retrieved value to get a full expanded folder path.